# How can i make arduino send sensor data to server using wifi?

Tags: arduino

So what i have so far in my code is to make my arduino able to send accelerometer and gyroscope data using Ethernet but I cant figure out how to make it wireless.

here is what i have so far:

`
    #include 
    #include
    #include

```
Byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0Xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xde 0x01 }; // Reserved Mac Address
 EthernetClient client;

 #define DHTPIN 2 // SENSOR PIN
    #define DHTTYPE DHT11 // SENSOR TYPE
 DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

 long previousMillis = 0;
 unsigned long currentMillis= 0;
 long interval = 250000; //READING INTERVAL

 int t = 0; // TEMPERATURE VAR
 int h = 0; // HUMIDITY VAR
 String data;

 Void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
      If (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
 Serial.println(“Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP”);
 }

 dht.begin();
 delay(10000); // GIVE THE SENSOR SOME TIME TO START

  h = (int) dht.readHumidity();
  t = (int) dht.readTemperature();

  data = “”;
 }

void loop(){

currentMillis = millis();
   if(currentMillis – previousMillis > interval) {    //READ ONLY ONCE PER           INTERVAL
  previousMillis = currentMillis;
    h = (int) dht.readHumidity();
   t = (int) dht.readTemperature();
  }
     data = “templ=” + t + “&hum1=” + h;          //THIS IS FOR PRINTING DATA TO WEBPAGE

   if (client.connect(www.*****.*************.com,80)) {       //REPLACE WITH SERVER ADDRESS
    client.println(“POST /add.php HTTP/1.1”);
   client.println(“Host: *****.*************.com,80”);         //SERVER ADDRESS HERE TOO
client.println(“Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded”);
 client.print(“Content-Length: “);
client.println(data.length());
 client.println();
 client.print(data);
 }

If (client.connected()) {
client.stop();  //Disconnect from the server
}

delay(300000);   //Wait five minutes before sending again

}
```

`

thank you

Comment: Do you have a WiFi or Bluetooth hardware module (or shield) for your Arduino?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a WiFi module like ESP8266.

You can also use it alone (without arduino) since it is a complete soc with io pins.

Comment: Unless when you have an Arduino model that includes WiFi functionality, like the Yún

Answer (score 0):

For small range you can use Xbee module or Bluetooth shield. For range, GSM shield is recommmended.